# Creating a CTTypesetter in Swift

Tags: cocoa, swift

I have an obj-c class that creates a CFAttributedStringRef:

```
- (CFAttributedStringRef)createAttributedStringWithByteRange:(NSRange)byteRange
{
  UInt8 bytes[byteRange.length];
  [self.data getBytes:&bytes range:byteRange];

  CFStringRef string = CFStringCreateWithBytes(NULL, bytes, byteRange.length, kCFStringEncodingUTF8, (byteRange.location == 0));

  return CFAttributedStringCreate(NULL, string, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)(self.textAttributes));
}
```

And I'm trying to call that function from a swift object, which should create a CTTypesetter:

```
let stringToDraw = self.storage.createAttributedStringWithByteRange(self.line.range)
let typesetter = CTTypesetterCreateWithAttributedString(stringToDraw)
```

Which gives me this build error:

```
error: cannot convert the expression's type 'CTTypesetter!' to type '$T3'
let typesetter = CTTypesetterCreateWithAttributedString(stringToDraw)
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem, the build error was misleading.

The actual problem was the previous line — my obj-c method returning `CFAttributedStringRef` bridges to `Unmanaged<CFAttributedString>` and needs to be brought into Swift as a managed object before it can be used, via the `takeRetainedValue()` method:

```
let stringToDraw = self.storage.createAttributedStringWithByteRange(self.line.range).takeRetainedValue()
let typesetter = CTTypesetterCreateWithAttributedString(stringToDraw)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to refer to the object type as a `CTTypesetterRef`, not `CTTypesetter`.

```
import Foundation
import CoreText


extension NSString
{
    func test() -> CTTypesetterRef
    {
        let attributedString : CFAttributedStringRef?
        let typesetter : CTTypeSetterRef = CTTypesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attributedString)
        return typesetter
    }
}
```

Comment: According to CTTypesetter.h, it returns `CTTypesetter!` not `CTTypeSetterRef`. With your code I get `cannot convert the expression's type 'CTTypesetter!' to type 'CFAttributedString!'` — https://gist.github.com/abhibeckert/dea1bda0a80bce67cdc6

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/reference/CTTypesetterRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005112-CH3-DontLinkElementID_4

Comment: That is the C/Obj-C reference. The swift one is `func CTTypesetterCreateWithAttributedString(_ string: CFAttributedString!) -> CTTypesetter!` — https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CTTypesetterRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CTTypesetterCreateWithAttributedString